# Is it possible to use .reduce with a const?

Tags: javascript, constants

I was completing an assignment in my coding bootcamp. They asked us to use .reduce to come up with a value. However, they initialized the total value using a const variable. When I would try to solve this problem using the const value, it kept throwing errors.

Because in my head, you can't change the const value. I simply replaced const with let. I'm not sure if I was supposed to change the code in that way but that's what I did.

```
const populationTotal = 0;

populationTotal = zooAnimals.reduce((total, item) => total + item.population, 0);

console.log(populationTotal);
```

If I keep the code the way it is, (const populationTotal = 0), it throws an error. When I changed the code (let populationTotal = 0), the problem was solved. Am I correct in thinking that you have to change const to let. Or is there a way to solve this problem with a const initial value?

Comment: Assign directly to the const - `const populationTotal = zooAnimals.reduce((total, item) => total + item.population, 0)`;

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), you can

Comment: A `const` is a "constant" meaning it cannot change. If you want to assign an unchanging value to a `const`, then calculate that value during the declaration of the variable, such as in @OriDrori's provided code snippet. If you don't want your variable to be unchangeable, then use `var` or `let` depending on your particular needs.

Comment: The code provided in the assignment is const populationTotal = 0. My question is whether or not there is a way to change this value after you declare it.

Comment: @JevonCochran I'll reiterate: It's literally impossible to change the value of a `const` after declaration. That's the entire point of a "constant". You must assign a `const` the value you want it to contain at time of declaration. If you want to be able to declare a variable before assigning a desired value, then it must be declared via `var` or `let`, not `const`.

Comment: So no there is no way to solve this problem without altering the code given (const populationTotal = 0)

Comment: Correct. It would absolutely need to be modified.

Answer (score -1):

> Am I correct in thinking that you have to change const to let.

Yes, if you want to mutate the variables value after declaration.

> Or is there a way to solve this problem with a const initial value

Sure. You can choose another initial value instead of `0`.

```
 const populationTotal = /* calculate the result here */;
```